# React select not displaying on html

Tags: reactjs, select

I have a div that should be displaying a dropdown menu that grabs the values from my database and display in a dropdown. The dropdown isnt displaying at all but when i inspect the page and dig through whats on there, the dropdown is there but i can't see it.

```
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 infoLanguageTop">
                <div className="card infoLanguageTop">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <span className="card-title">Deck Name: </span>
                            <div className='container'>
                                <select value={this.state.decks} onChange={this.handleDeckChange}>
                                    {this.state.decks.map(decks => (
                                        <option value={decks.deckName} />
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                I am writing in: 
                                <Dropdown options={languageOptions} onChange={this._onSelect} placeholder="Select a language" />
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                I would like to translate to: 
                                <Dropdown options={languageOptions} onChange={this._onSelect} placeholder="Select a language" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap Dropdown or something custom?

Comment: that react drop down is just an npm package that i found called react-dropdown. Ive also tested it where i deleted that code and didnt import the package and just left the the <select value etc etc and nothing still showed up.